# Parent Service Contract field showing name as ID when shown on List View

Tags: related-list, list-view, servicecloud, contracts

I'm using the Standard Service Contracts, with Parent Service Contract. When looking on the actual record, the parent shows up as expected.

[image]

However, when adding the same field to a list view or a related list, it shows the ID of the parent. Additionally, clicking the link takes you to the child service contract.

[image]

Is this a configuration issue somewhere?

**Edit:** I've used a formula field to get the name of the parent contract and display it on the list views and related lists, but I'm still curious if anyone has an idea on why this happened?

Comment: Looks like you are using incorrect field in the related list. In detail page is it formula field?

Comment: No, these screenshots are from before I created the formula field to work around this. They are indeed referencing the same field

Comment: When you click the ID does it take you to the parent agreement record as you would expect, or does it go to something else?

Comment: @PaulH. it goes to the child record - it shows the ID of the parent service contract, but the link goes to the child.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @Roxy521, no I ended up putting a formula field to mimic the lookup field link and that worked ok